# Send Email from Public App - Sharepoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, email, sharepoint-hosted-app

```
Function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
    'properties': {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
        'From': from,
        'To': { 'results': [to] },
        'Body': body,
        'Subject': subject
    }
}
   ),
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: function (data) {
   console.log('success')
},
error: function (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
}
});
```

I'm using this function to send e-mails with a Sharepoint Hosted App with sucess, but I can only send e-mails to the users from the Sharepoint Site (I know this is for security) but My app will be used in a public web site where I can't validate the user will be in my sharepoint site (he don't need to be) and I need send the e-mail to him. There is any way besides change my application to Provider Hosted and use

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail
```

In my c# code? It's a conversion from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013 and we can't add the cost of a provider hosting too this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Year, I didn't find a way, but I found this: https://medium.com/@mariusc23/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-b53319616782

As my client don't need more than 12000 mails for month, the free API was enough for my demand. I hope it can help any if anyone found the same problem o/

Comment: i know it's been 2 years by posting this answer,i tried to followed link you shared in your answer but it is not useful to me i tried but it's i think it's asking for some internal setting before generating API Key like DKIM missing and SPF error see here(http://i.stack.imgur.com/YfVox.png)

Comment: Sorry, they changed a lot in two years and I don't have a MailChipm account to check the new configuration, but as sharepoint public web sites will be dead in a couple months, you should check a migration for your web site for a new plataform.